# How to find a chord with length $1/11$ of the function $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}x^n$, where $x\in[0,1]$ and $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, mobius-function

Let $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function, see if your need its definition from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html), and we consider the function $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}x^n,\tag{1}$$
over real numbers $[0,1]$.

> **Question.** I would like to know how to find (the prime number theorem and the universal chord theorem, see if you need it this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_chord_theorem), imply the existence) *a chord of length* $\frac{1}{11}$ *for our function* $(1)$. **Many thanks.**

I don't know if it is obvious how to find it (I know how are the graphs of functions $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{n}x^n$, over the same interval, for a large and fixed integer $N$), or well if it is very difficult and thus we only can to  find an interval containing our chord.

### References:

[1] Ralph P. Boas, *A Primer of Real Functions*, Mathematical Association of America 4th Edition (1996).

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. That was very nice of you, but I am not sure I deserved it. Really, it looks like I still need to give a _rigorous_ proof that $\hat{f}$ is a good estimation of $f$.

Comment: I accepted your answer and I've considered also the bounty for your question. I think that your is a very very question. Any case I accept your words. I need also to think also about the exercise. Many thanks @polfosol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we know that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}=0$$
then we can start with $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

I have not found any closed form formulas for your function and the specific value of $\frac1{11}$, and I strongly suspect that there is none. So I suggest that we should stick to the approximations/estimations.

First, note that for $x\in(0,1)$ the value of $x^n$ quickly converges to zero. So it seems that a fairly large value of $N$ results in a good approximation of $f(x)$, i.e.
$$\hat{f}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{200}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}x^n,\quad 0<x<1$$
looks accurate enough for practical applications. A plot of this function in the interval $[0,1]$ is like this:

[image: plot]

And let Mathematica handle the rest:

```
f[x_]:= Sum[x^n MoebiusMu[n]/n, {n,1,200}]
FindRoot[f[x]- f[x+1/11] == 0, {x,.4}]
```

which results in

```
{x-> 0.534191}
```

Now you can test the result:

```
{f[x], f[x+1/11]} /.%

{0.334188, 0.334188}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your great answer, I am going to study the details/computations. I think that get approximations/estimations is a good way, I asked the questions to determine a chord of length $1/11$ but of course to find such segment maybe can be impossible, thus I think that  the question/answer with the purpose to get an approximation is more  reasonable.

Comment: @user243301 I am glad that my answer was helpful. What I am still wondering is: where did the $\frac1{11}$ come from? Did you just pick a random number or is it some special value? :)

Comment: Just that the denominator is not a small number like $2$ or $4$ neither a very large number like $10000$.

Comment: @user243301 For what it's worth, you can test the code for free at [Wolfram cloud](https://lab.wolframcloud.com).

Comment: Many thanks, you are friendly, in fact I thought that this was not free. I am going to sign in it, in next days.